# Git on Linux MInt. I can't push commit to my GitHub account. Terminal breaks down

Tags: git, github, linux-mint

It's requiring login and password but it's glitched so when I try to type in my password no characters appear.

How to fix this bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a password, it doesn't show the characters. This is intentional to prevent other people looking over your shoulder from seeing the password (or from other people seeing the password if it's being screen-recorded).

Copy-pasting the access token and then hitting enter will enter the password.

Alternatively, you could just enable ssh, and then you won't have to use an access token or enter a password.

Comment: George, if an answer solved your problem, please be sure to accept it by clicking the check mark next to the post. That will mark your question as resolved.